# How do I show a Form in maximized state in the same monitor as its parent?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, position

How do I show a Form in maximized state in the same monitor as its parent?

I tried to run the following codes in a dual monitor system:

```
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
      Form form2 = new Form();
      form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
      form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
      form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

but form2 is always shown in the primary monitor, even though its parent is on the secondary monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the owner (parent), by passing it to [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
form2.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: Thanks! But how could this make difference? MSDN doc says that ShowDialog without parameter should "Shows the form as a modal dialog box with the currently active window set as its owner."

Comment: Yes, to reproduce it I just created a simple Winforms app from the wizard of VS 2008 then only add a button and the button1_Click event. I just tried using VS 2012 Express and still got this issue.

Comment: No, I mean both in VS2008 and VS2012, it works only if I pass in `this`

Comment: It works as expected without passing `this` when I remove the line to maximize the window state. But it doesn't work when I set `WindowState` to `Maximized`.